# Convert IniPreferences to Map?

Tags: java, dictionary

How would I convert [IniPreferences](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/ini4j/IniPreferences.html) to a Map in Java?

I currently have

```
public static Map<String, String> configMap;

Ini ini = new Ini(configIni);
    java.util.prefs.Preferences prefs = new IniPreferences(ini);
configMap = new HashMap<>();
    configMap.put("Version", prefs.node("Settings").get("Version", null));
```

However this would require me to insert the key for anything added to the ini making it a pain to maintain.

The prefs.node will always be settings however preferably they would be combined into configMap.

**How would I automate this?**

Comment: I would look at using a different API to read the ".ini" files.  The "ini4j" library shows the signs of being a project where the main developers have lost interest.  Also, I would try to avoid having to convert.  Use one model (either properties or ini) for **both** the config file **and** throughout your application.

Comment: The problem is that the information models for Ini and Properties are fundamentally different.  If you try to map an Ini structure down to a Properties (i.e. Map<String, String>) structure you lose information.  And that is likely to be the information that caused you to chose an Ini file over a Properties file in the first place.

Comment: @StephenC Right, okay. Thank you for the insight.